# Running a cell twice in jupyter and keep the count the same

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter

I am changing the question completely because it was not expressed properly before:

Lets say I have a huge df with millions of rows and I want to replace a special characters ä and ö in Column. I do this:

```
print(df['Column'].str.contains('ä|ö', regex=True).sum())
umlaut_dict = {'ä':'ae','ö':'oe'}
df.Column.replace(umlaut_dict, regex=True, inplace=True)
print(df['Column'].str.contains('ä|ö', regex=True).sum())
```

The first time it works like a charm, shows the number of characters to replace and then confirms if all have been replaced. When the same cell is ran a 2nd time it shows 2 0s.

My question is:

1. Are these things I need to worry or the whole notebook is supposed to run once?
2. Is there a way to keep the original number without creating a copy of the df before transformation?

Comment: Most pandas operations generate a new dataframe, leaving the original intact, unless you specifically say `inplace=True`.  Because of that, copying is usually unnecessary.  Do you really need all the intermediate dataframes?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: I really do not need them Tim Roberts. Just could not find a better way to deal with it. Very new to this :)

Comment: I changed the question completely to deal with a specific case, when I encounter an error again, I will make it a new specific topic @Michael Butscher